# gradle task is ambiguous due to custom build variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have an android project with a 'debugMock' build type for connecting to a mock api. When my CI (App Center) tries to run tests I get the following error

```
Task 'testDebug' is ambiguous in root project 'my-project'. Candidates are: 'testDebugDebug', 'testDebugDebugMock', 'testDebugMockUnitTest', 'testDebugRelease', 'testDebugUnitTest'.
```

This is as a result of the `gradle testDebug` command and I can reproduce locally. How can I avoid the above error? My build config is pretty standard:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debugMock.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        debugMock {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the name, which causes confusion:

```
mock {
    initWith debug
    applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
    matchingFallbacks = ['debug']

}
```

Comment: Just to note that your initWith syntax didn't work for me, but removing debug from the buildType name did!

Comment: @aaronmarino fixed that; the double quotes were the problem.